# How to pass "parameters" from figure to figure when using \tikzexternalize

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external, externalize

On the first figure below ( \tikzexternalize is disabled) the diagram on the right is drawn using the possibility of the "calc" library to draw parallel lines.

I need this schematic to be in an independent figure (the second figure). This works if \tikzexternalize is disabled (this may not be normal, Tikz seems to keep coordinates in memory).

On the other hand as soon as \tikzexternalize is activated, the second figure is not generated.

What is the solution for passing parameters from an external figure to another external figure?

[image]

```
% !TeX program =Xelatex+shell-escape
% !TeX encoding = utf8
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external,calc,intersections}
%\tikzexternalize
 
\begin{document}
\tikzsetnextfilename{testExterne} % Nom du fichier de sortie de la figure

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[dashed,blue,name path=Rg] (0,0)coordinate(P)node[inner sep=0,label=P]{$\times$}  --++(5cm,0);
\draw[-latex,ultra thick,blue] (P) --++(2cm,0) node[above]{$ {R_{g \to d}}$};

\draw[dashed,blue,name path=BC] (1,-3.5)coordinate(B) node[inner sep=0,label=B]{$\times$} --++(2,2.5)coordinate(C) node[inner sep=0,label=C]{$\times$}  coordinate[pos=1.4](ff) -- (ff);
\path [name intersections={of=Rg and BC,by=E}];

\draw[dashed] (2,-5)coordinate(D)node[inner sep=0,label=D]{$\times$} -- (E)node[inner sep=0,label=E]{$\times$} ;

\begin{scope}[shift={(5cm,-6cm)}]
 \draw[-latex,ultra thick,red] (0,0) coordinate(a1)--++(2cm,0)coordinate(a2) node[below]{$ {R_{g \to d}}$};
 
 \draw[name path=a1,dashed] (a1) -- ++($(C)-(B)$)coordinate[pos=2.5](ff) --(ff);

 \draw[name path=a2,dashed] (a2) -- ++($(E)-(D)$)coordinate[pos=1.5](ff) --(ff);
 \path [name intersections={of=a1 and a2,by=a3}];
 
 \draw[-latex,thick] (a2) -- (a3);
 \draw[-latex,thick] (a3) -- (a1);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[-latex,ultra thick,red] (0,0) coordinate(a1)--++(2cm,0)coordinate(a2) node[below]{$ {R_{g \to d}}$};
 
 \draw[name path=a1,dashed] (a1) -- ++($(C)-(B)$)coordinate[pos=2.5](ff) --(ff);

 \draw[name path=a2,dashed] (a2) -- ++($(E)-(D)$)coordinate[pos=1.5](ff) --(ff);
 \path [name intersections={of=a1 and a2,by=a3}];
 
 \draw[-latex,thick] (a2) -- (a3);
 \draw[-latex,thick] (a3) -- (a1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: TikZ externalize creates and runs a separate process of LaTeX standalone.  Processes do not share memory, or anyting else except files.  You could run several tikzpictures in one standalone using the `multi={tikzpicture}` or `tikz` options.

Comment: @JohnKormylo can you explain multi={tikzpicture}?

Comment: Here is one example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/636776/show-plots-conditionally-progressively